# ember-cli with EmbeddedRecordsMixin not embedded model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, serialization

This is my first question in Stackoverflow. :)
My problem is the next:

I am trying to send a JSON to my API (via POST) with this format:

```
Events: [
{
  id: 2,
  name: "foo",
  Eventcategories: [1,2]
}]
```

Embedding a hasMany Eventcategories association with EmbeddedRecordsMixin and this not appear in JSON serialized, only this:

```
Events: [
{
  id: 2,
  name: "foo"
}]
```

I have try this using ActiveModelSerializer and RESTSerializer without results.

GET response works without any problems.

I have an ember-cli project with these models:

--------event.js ----------------

```
var event = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  Eventcategories: DS.hasMany('eventcategory')
});
export default event;
```

---------eventcategoy.js ------------------

```
var eventcategory = DS.Model.extend({
   tipo: DS.attr('string'),
   Events: DS.hasMany('event')
});
export default eventcategory;
```

And this is my serializers:

-------event.js----------------------------

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {
    Eventcategories: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

------eventcategory.js --------------------

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {
    Events: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

---

Could you help me?

Regards.

Angel

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the problem, it works with this:

Models/foo.js:

```
var foo = DS.Model.extend({
...,
...,
...,
bars: DS.hasMany('bar', {async: true})
});
export default foo;
```

Models/bar.js:

```
var bar = DS.Model.extend({
...,
Foos: DS.hasMany('foo', {async: true})
});

export default bar;
```

Serializer/foo.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {  
    Bars: {
     embedded: 'always'
    }
  }
});
```

Serializer/bar.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {    
    Foos: {
          embedded: 'always'
        }
   }
});
```